# can't get html from webpage

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

file_get_htm return false, but if i try get data to string, then everything is ok ..

```
$url = "http://www.dkb-handball-bundesliga.de/de/dkb-hbl/spielplan/spielplan-chronologisch/";

$output = file_get_contents($url);
print_r($output); //this return string 

$html = file_get_html($url);
print_r($html); //this return false
```

i was try with curl, but everything is the same...

if i cgange url for example, everything work ok...

```
$url='http://www.dkb-handball-bundesliga.de/de/s/spiele/2014-2015/dkb-handball-bundesliga/1--spieltag--bergischer-hc-vs-sg-bbm-bietigheim/';
```

Comment: If this works with one page but not another, perhaps the HTML you are retrieving is broken.

Answer (score -1):

You will get data from this:

```
    <?php
    // put your code here
        include_once './simple_html_dom.php';
        $html = file_get_html("http://www.dkb-handball-bundesliga.de/");   
        $links = array();
        foreach($html->find('a') as $a) {
            $links[] = $a->href;
        }
        print_r($links);
    ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>My elements</th> 
            <a href="/hello1">Hello world 1</a>
            <a href="/hello2">Hello world 2</a>
            <a href="/hello3">Hello world 3</a>
            <a href="/hello4">Hello world 4</a>
            <a href="/hello5">Hello world 5</a>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>



    <?php
       // You need to know the location of the file that you are calling.
        include_once './simple_html_dom.php';
        $html = file_get_html("http://localhost/PhpHelpers/examples.html");   
        $links = array();
        foreach($html->find('a') as $key => $val) {
            $links[$key] = $val; 
        }
        print_r($links);
    ?>
```

Comment: yes, i have error when posting here...i used single quotes, but isn't help

Comment: Maybe this post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080731/simple-dom-file-get-html-returns-nothing

Comment: Are you including the library?                                                                                                include('simple_html_dom.php');  
    $html = file_get_html("http://google.com");                                                                                             var_dump($html);

Comment: Try with another website. And print the result.

Comment: of course that i include library...if not, then script don't work when i change url...

Comment: I had looking for around the web. Look this site: http://nimishprabhu.com/top-10-best-usage-examples-php-simple-html-dom-parser.html

Comment: don't parse data for first time...so i know all of that...here is the problem because i can't fetch data to html object, only to string...i try to get object from string with str_get_html, but same all...this return false...

Comment: can you send me your source?

Comment: The problem in your code is that you cant call a path of a website, because you need to call a page where you could find a real file example: when you call the root of one page with this function "file_get_html" you can get all the index elements in that website. That is my conclusion.

Comment: of course, works fine, but try to parse this link http://www.dkb-handball-bundesliga.de/de/dkb-hbl/spielplan/spielplan-chronologisch/

Comment: But if you create a file in your localhost you can get all the elements in that file. I have tested.

Comment: If you are the webmaster of that page you know your website structure and that could help you to get what you want. Regards.